# How to watch a CLR exception in C++?

Tags: c++, clr

My program is written in C++ (Visual Studio 2019), but calls the external COM-based dll functions, which apparently implemented on .NET framework. When I call a function of those dll, EEFileLoadException is thrown from the dll and the debugger broke at _CxxThrowException, apparently inside vcruntime.
Probably this occurs because some assembly files are missing and the CLR thrown System.IO.FileLoadException, which contains FileName property. I would like to see the property to know what file is missing.

Even though I set the debugger mixed-mode, it cannot be broke at a line in which FileLoadException was thrown inside the CLR code. Therefore I cannot watch the contents of the FileLoadException itself.

The last resort is pExceptionObject, the first argument of _CxxThrowException, which probably is a pointer to EEFileLoadException. However, "(EEFileLoadException*)pExceptionObject" in the watch window does not work. It only shows "EEFileLoadException is undefined".

How can I give the debbuger the type information of EEFileLoadException? How can I get the FileName?

[Visual Studio broke inside _CxxThrowException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXKey.png)

Comment: Have you started/attached the debugger in managed mode?

Comment: The debugger broke too early, still buried deep inside the CLR.  You can only diagnose the managed exception after it is created and thrown.  Press F5 to keep running.  If the exception is handled by the managed code then use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and tick the checkbox for CLR exceptions.